# How do I make permanent changes to a website that doesn't belong to me?

Tags: html, css, text-editor

My dad's company asked me to change the menu bar of their website. Basically, I just opened the page source (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>) of the website, copied and pasted all the HTML and CSS to notepad++ and changed some of the HTML code (just to try it out and test it to see if it works) and saved it as an HTML file. But how do I permanently save the changes to the actual website so that everyone can see it? Sorry if this sounds like a noob question. My HTML skills are at beginner level.

Comment: you are just changing on your browser ,you need to do this actual html content of that page resided in server

Comment: you can connect to the server using filezilla or similar ftp client. You'll need the ftp username / password. you may need to contact the hosting provider for these

Comment: @andrew — That's an assumption. I can't remember the last time I dealt with a website that used FTP to manage it.

Comment: How websites works: https://youtu.be/D8c4JZW73cM :) - and basically - you need access to server, where the pages are stored

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to edit arbitrary websites. If it was, every major website would be covered in spam and pornography.

You have to have access to the server. The specifics depend on how the site is set up. There might be a content management system to edit it through, there might be a SFTP server you drop static files in, there might be any number of other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

This desktop save isn't gonna work. You need access to the original files of the hosted website! 
Like, if its a wordpress blog, you need to get access to its admin-panel 
or if its a tailored website, you need to get its FTP access, then you can download that page, make changes and re-upload it on the same location - that's it!

Both require some credentials - for example if your website url is **example.com**, then it may be something like:
for wordpress: example.com/wp-admin/login.php

for site: ftp.example.com

Answer (score 0):

The code you see on the browser are just built out of some [raw data](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-browser-rendering-works-behind-the-scenes-6782b0e8fb10/) that are provided (sent) by the server for your browser. The browser engine makes its own version of source code from that data to be able to display the page to the end user. This code is most probably very different from the actual source code that the developers have written.

Also, You don't have the permission to change the website from your browser. You need to access to the server and make your changes from there.

Just like you can't make changes to a tv programme by changing the audio/video settings of your own television and you need to access to the devices in the studio to make real changes to it.